# SceneKit - How do I attach a particle emitter to a node in a scene using the Xcode editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, editor, scenekit, particle-system

I can't figure out how to attach my particle emitter to a node in my scene using the Xcode editor. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnparticlesystem) says 'You can attach a particle system to a node in the Xcode scene editor to preview the particle system in your scene.'

I know how to do this programatically, but can't figure out how to do it inside of the editor. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it is only possible to do that programmatically. The editor's features are lacking, and the majority of customizations for any element need to be done programmatically.

But you already know how, so you're golden!

Comment: I think you're correct Dan. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in the editor yet.

Answer (score 3):

In the Xcode SceneKit Scene Editor you can open the Object Library (⌃⌥⌘3) and drag a particle system from there to the scene.

You can also use the Scene Graph View on the left of the editor, select a node, and then use the contextual menu (right click) or gear icon in the toolbar at the bottom to add a particle system to an existing node.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This only seems to work for adding a new particle emitter though. Is it possible to add an existing particle emitter?